# Vue 3 - Continue uploading files in the background while browsing the website

Tags: vue.js, file-upload, background-process, vuejs3

I would like to make a page with Vue 3 where a user could start an upload of a (very large) file, and after that he's able to go to other pages while the upload is still going on in the background. A plus would be a small widget showing me progress anywhere on a website, and a notification when the upload has completed.

I may have found something, but it's written only for Vue 2: https://github.com/Akryum/vue-router-multi-view

Comment: Please ask specific questions. No one will be able to convert an entire library to vue3 for you.

Comment: `go to other pages while the upload is still going on` - it could be a use case for `<keep-alive></keep-alive>` with vue-router

Comment: @tauzN It's true, I should have asked if it was possible to do it in Vue, but somehow i've missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solution was actually quite simple... I've just put the upload component outside the router component in the main app template and everything worked.

Comment: Then may I ask how do you check if the operation is still processing to prevent users from refreshing the page because if they refresh it will cancel the request?